# PHP mail link adding C:, attempting to go to a local file instead of a web browser

Tags: php, email

```
$noteContent="Contacted from <a href=\'".$data['PageURL']."\' target=\'_blank\'>".$data['PageURL']."</a>";

$headers .= 'Bcc: xxx@gmail.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ".$from."\n";
$headers .= "X-Priority: 1\n";
$message=$noteContent.'<br /><br />';
$message.="Name: ".$data['first'].' '.$data['last'].'<br />';
$message.="Email: ".$data['email'].'<br />';
$message.="Phone: ".$data['phone'].'<br /><br />';
$message.="<span style='color:#900;font-weight:bold;'>Please call, bla bla bla bla.</span>";
$message=nl2br($message);
mail($mailto, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

The problem is that I'm sending this through, and it's outputting correctly when you look at it.  Looks like a simple link with the pageurl.  However, its actually linking to: res://ieframe.dll/syntax.htm#\'http://www.somewebsite.com\'

So it opens up in their browser as a local file.  What am I doing wrong here that is causing that to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string is enclosed with double quotes, so you don't need to escape the single quotes:

```
$noteContent="Contacted from <a href=\'" . $data['PageURL'] . "\' ...
```

Should just be:

```
$noteContent="Contacted from <a href='" . $data['PageURL'] . "' ...
```

Comment: I feel pretty silly with that one :p, works perfectly now thank you.